# If i like to get the latest feeds from group / news feed what to use in the since key?

Tags: date, facebook-graph-api

im using the graph api to get the latest news from groups and news feed , i wander what is the right date to use ? the update_time or create_time in the json results ?

"created_time": 1327392578,
or
"updated_time": 1327392578,

Answer (score 1):

> im using the graph api to get the latest news from groups and news
>   feed , i wander what is the right date to use ? the update_time or
>   create_time in the json results ?

created_time